# Which shell script does delete my directory?

Tags: linux

My application directory is deleted by some shell script each 3 weeks。 The trouble is these shell scripts were written by different team members, and shell scripts have more than 1k files(each script has its purpose, but a bug in some script lead to the problem).

I tried to search "rm -rf" in these scripts, but it returns too many matched scripts. Except for audit and inotifywait, does it have a way to find which shell script deleted my directory ?

Comment: -1 your title makes no sense, "Which does shell script delete my directory?" isn't proper english, and furthermore, you're in london, and the body of your question is worded fine. So you should know your title is not properly written.

Comment: @barlop: You know it'd have been easier for you just to click 'Edit' and delete one word than write out that whole, pointless comment.

Comment: @PotatoCat by your reasoning -  likewise- (it'd have been easier for you to edit it than to write your comment suggesting that I do)

Comment: @barlop: I'm not the one complaining the title "isn't proper english" while using improper English.

Comment: @PotatoCat  No, you're complaining that i've used improper english in a comment, yet at the same time you leave a title with improper english. And you keep shifting the goalposts to try to avoid appearing hypocritical/inconsistent. in telling me to change the title while excusing yourself from doing so.

Comment: @barlop: I didn't write the title, and it's good that you picked up on the hypocrisy implication. Hint hint.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what PID and what command deleted a file, you're going to have to use the audit daemon. A link introducing the concept is here: http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/01/a-brief-introduction-to-auditd/

Alternatively, you can use something like NetIQ Sentinel to keep track of your systems. That's expensive for such a single purpose, though.

Also, 1k shell scripts on a single system? That's unmanageable. This is what containerization and virtualization is for, or at least some kind of workload separation / farming. You have so many things going on with this one system that you're starting to feel the pain of it.